# Datatables with MultiFilter (Text Input), MultiFilter Select and preselcted/preset Search Values

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTables (https://www.datatables.net/) in combination with Bootstrap to manage the display of a huge table in a nice way.

As I am aiming to get a good user experience, I want to open the table with some initial settings:
1) Prefill the Search Field (this is working)
2) Preselect one of the Column Filter Dropdowns (this is where I am stuck)

I tried basically all kind of solutions I found on SO and DT Forums but to no success.

Here's my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ckmuc/83n1uxsd/7/

```
var tabl = $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
"oSearch": {"sSearch":'2009'}, 
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns([1,2,3,4]).every( function () {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
      .on( 'change', function () {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
        );
                  column
          .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
          .draw();
        });

    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
        var val = $('<div/>').html(d).text();
      select.append( '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>' );
    });
  });


        this.api().columns([0]).every( function () {
    var column = this;
            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
      if ( column.search() !== this.value ) {
        column
          .search( this.value )
          .draw();
      }
            });
        });
}
});
```

*I have also posted this question in Datatables Forum and will combine all answer from both sources for future reference, if someone is facing same scenario (https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/40587/datatables-with-multifilter-multifilterselect-and-preselection-search-and-select-filter#latest)*

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "Preselect one of the Column Filter Dropdowns (this is where I am stuck)"? Not sure I'm following what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of Deep 3015 all works now as desired:

```
initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns([1, 2, 3, 4]).every(function() {

        var column = this;
        var c           = column[0]; /* get column id */
        var select = $('<select class="col'+c+'"><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );
            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          var val = $('<div/>').html(d).text();
          select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });


        if (column[0] == 2) { /*here 2 is the third column */
          var valforcol = 'New York'; /* This value will be preset when initially calling this script */
          $(".col2").val(valforcol).change(); /* Set the selected value based on value valforcol */
         column.search(valforcol ? '^' + valforcol + '$' : '', true, false).draw() /*apply filter*/
        }
      });
```

Can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/ckmuc/4h0vyc45/

Solution was to assign a class to the select fields and to assigen the "selected value" to that class later.

Answer (score 2):

As far I am understanding you want to have pre selected select filter options.So this can be one of the solution for achieving it.

```
 initComplete: function() {
  this.api().columns([1, 2, 3, 4]).every(function() {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );
        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
      var val = $('<div/>').html(d).text();
      select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
    });

    /*selecting the column to filter*/
    if (column[0] == 2) { /*here 2 is the third column */
      var valforcol = $(select).children().eq(3).val(); /* 3 is fourth option of third column */
      $(select).children().eq(3).attr("selected", true); /* adding selected attribute*/
      column.search(valforcol ? '^' + valforcol + '$' : '', true, false).draw() /*apply filter*/
    }


  });


  this.api().columns([0]).every(function() {
    var column = this;
    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
      if (column.search() !== this.value) {
        column
          .search(this.value)
          .draw();
      }
    });
  });

}
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/6wox4gkg/)  for demonstration

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

I have updated the fiddle to reflect, what I wanted to achieve: 
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ckmuc/4h0vyc45/)